# Postbacks in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there a way to check which link/button was clicked from a form besides using

```
if(isset($_POST['myvar']))
{
//if true do this
}
else
{//do this}
```

or a querystring?

My page has a jquery drop down and thus the above isset function is not working as the form for login is contained in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with PHP, but going the jQuery route, you can create a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="postSource" id="postSource" />
```

and then wire up some event handlers to modify that value before the page is posted.

```
$('#myControl1, #myControl2').change(function()
{
    $('#postSource').val($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

.NET uses a similar technique, I think. Then on server side, you just access the posted value of the 'postSource' field.